Using llvm-objcopy to remove symbols from static library (mach-o)
I am trying to use llvm-objcopy (or llvm-strip) to remove a symbol from a static library (mach-o). I am doing the following:
$ llvm-objcopy --strip-symbol "__ZNK7WebCore17JSDOMGlobalObject22scriptExecutionContextEv" library.a library-stripped.a

It gives no errors and generates library-stripped.a, but when I run llvm-nm -A on library-stripped.a, the symbol is still there:
$ llvm-nm -A library-stripped.a | grep "__ZNK7WebCore17JSDOMGlobalObject22scriptExecutionContextEv"
<lots of U references and the T symbol>

I've tried similar with llvm-stripe. Am I getting the syntax wrong or something?
